# Advanced gallery with Thumbnails and Preview image with Magnific popup

Tags: jquery, magnific-popup

i have a problem with an advanced gallery with the great Magnific Popup.

Logic:
1. after clicking on Thumbnails -> the image in Preview should be changed (that works OK)
2. after clicking on Preview image -> it should open the Magnific gallery but with gallery set from Thumbnails.

I prepared a [`FIDDLE`](https://jsfiddle.net/ymthpjjq/2/)

If someone can help me, i'l be very very glad. I lost about 10 hours with it :(

Comment: I found the way how to fill the gallery data with items, but there is still some little problem with the opened image. It opens everytime on position 1.

https://jsfiddle.net/ymthpjjq/5/

Comment: Solved: https://jsfiddle.net/ymthpjjq/7/

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

https://js fiddle.net/ymthpjjq/7/

Best helper: other Stackoverflow Q&A  :)

Comment: please explain your answer, and include essential parts of the code here.